# Submitting a pull request for a Julia package in Pkg v1.1

Tags: julia

I want to add a feature to FITSIO package and submit a pull request. What is the current workflow for that? Before Pkg 1.0 there were `Pkg.checkout` and `Pkg.submit` functions. Are there similar commands that I can run in Pkg v1.1?

Of course, I can manually fork the repository on Github, make changes and submit a pull request. But I wonder if there are convenient shortcuts in Pkg 1.1 for that?

### Update

Here is a [useful guide](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/develop-a-local-version-of-a-registered-package-and-submit-changes-as-a-pull-request/24868) that I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Pkg.develop`](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/api/#Pkg.develop) (or the `develop` Pkg REPL command) which will download a full git-clone of the package and put it in `$HOME/.julia/dev` by default. There you can make your changes and push as usual.

`Pkg.develop` can also take a path as an argument, so if you have `git clone`d the repository to some other more convenient folder (as compared to `$HOME/.julia/dev`) and prefer to work there you can "install" that path by `Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(path = "path/to/clone"))` and it should be available to load from within Julia.

EDIT:

`checkout` has been replaced by two new things:

1. if the intention is just to install the master branch of the package you now do `pkg> add Example#master` (or `Pkg.add(PackageSpec(name="Example", rev="master"))`);
2. If the intention is to modify the code you use `Pkg.develop`.

There does not exist something like Pkg.submit in the new package manager; you have to git push and make a PR yourself.

Comment: Thanks, are there shortcuts in v1.1 similar to `checkout `and `submit` that we had before v1.0?

Comment: I edited the answer to include information about that.